# Translate German country names to French

Tags: ruby, translation, rails-i18n

I got a YAML file with the following structure containing country names in German:

```
countries:
      country_1:  "Schweiz"
      country_2:  "Deutschland"
      country_3:  "Italien"
      country_4:  "Frankreich"
      country_6:  "Afghanistan"
```

I can import the file to Ruby and save it as a `Hash`.

```
require 'yaml'
yml = YAML.load_file('countries.yml')
countries = yml['countries']
```

I want to translate them into French. I thought that this should be a fairly simple task using `I18nCountryTranslations`, but I'm stuck. Is there a way to do this with built-in Ruby tools? Or do I need the whole Rails framework for this? Or an external API?

Comment: What do you mean, "stuck"?

Comment: Another word for - "I don't know what to do next" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `countries` gem to get the translation

Just install the gem and add `require 'countries'` to your ruby file. You can follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/hexorx/countries)

```
c = ISO3166::Country.find_country_by_name('united states')
c.translations['fr'] #=> "États-Unis"
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the translation ... I want to translate them so that instead of "Schweiz" it says "Suisse"

Comment: i think `countries` gem can help you

Comment: See the second link in my answer. You can find all the translations.

Answer (score 0):

The country names are already translated and available in almost any format. Just [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=country%20name%20translations%20in%20yaml). Here is an [example](https://mledoze.github.io/countries/) in CVS, XML and YAML formats.

If this file is required for some of your projects, I would simply have those country's in the original yaml file like so:

```
de:
   countries:
      country_1:  "Schweiz"
      country_2:  "Deutschland"
      country_3:  "Italien"
      country_4:  "Frankreich"
      country_6:  "Afghanistan"
fr:
   countries:
      country_1:  "Schweiz in French"
      country_2:  "Deutschland in French"
```